# use color from a class's static field xamarin.forms

Tags: c#, binding, xamarin.forms, resources

Let's say I have a static class as follows

```
namespace MyNameSpace {
    static class MyClass {
        public static Color MyColor = Color.Red;

    }
}
```

I am creating a class with these fields to use them within other c# classes. Is it also possible to use the same static them within xaml. something like this?

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         xmlns:Cols="clr-namespace:MyNameSpace"
         BackgroundColor="{Cols:MyClass.MyColor}" />
```

Or some other way using static resources?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [x:Static markup extension](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/xaml/xaml-basics/xaml_markup_extensions/#The_xStatic_Markup_Extension).

```
<ContentPage ... 
     BackgroundColor="{x:Static Cols:MyClass.MyColor}"..
```

`x:Static` can access one of the following:

- a public static field
- a public static property
- a public constant field
- an enumeration member.